# ORA-01843 - not a valid month - only working with a few date formats

Tags: sql, oracle, toad

Using Toad for Oracle.

My initial table has dates in the format of the following `2020-07-01T00:00:00`. I'm using the following code to remove everything starting from `T` from every date:

```
SELECT NVL(SUBSTR(date_column_0, 0, INSTR(date_column_0, 'T')-1), date_column_0) as date_column_0 FROM original_table;
```

These dates I have in another test table, where date_column type is VARCHAR:

```
date_column
2020-07-01
2020-08-01
2020-09-01
```

**I need to convert those dates to YYYYMM format (i.e. 202007).** So far I have tried

1)

```
select to_char(cast(date_column as date, 'YYYYMM')) from test_table;
select to_char(to_date(date_column, 'YYYYMM')) from test_table
```

Both of these yield the error `ORA-01843 - not a valid month`.

2)

```
select to_char(cast(column_6 as date), 'YYYYMM') from test_table;
select to_char(cast(column_6 as date), 'YYYY/MM/DD') from test_table;
```

Both yield the error `ORA-01861: literal does not match format string`.

---

For some reason,

```
select to_char(cast(date_column as date, 'YYYY/MM/DD')) from test_table;
select to_char(to_date(date_column, 'YYYY/MM/DD')) from test_table
```

both work and shows the dates in the format `01-JUL-20`, which I obviously do not want. If I select the similar date format from dual, it also works perfectly (the code below yields `202004``):

```
select to_char(cast(sysdate as date),'YYYYMM') from dual;
---> 202004
```

---

EDIT 23.4.2020
I think I figured it out though should have figured it out much earlier... **I have to first select a SUBSTRING from the VARCHAR "date" so that it matches the date format I want to convert it to.** So,

```
SELECT ((SUBSTR(date_column, 9, 2)  || SUBSTR(date_column, 6,2)  || SUBSTR(date_column, 1,4))) FROM test_table;
```

is the SUBSTRING command to select the date in the format DDMMYYYY. And the following command

```
SELECT to_char(cast(SUBSTR(date_column, 9, 2)  || SUBSTR(date_column, 6,2)  || SUBSTR(date_column, 1,4) as date, 'DD-MM-YYYY')) FROM test_table;
```

is the command to convert it to date.

Comment: Unrelated, but: `cast(sysdate as date)` can be simplified to `sysdate`

Comment: Is `date_column` really a `varchar`?

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name Yes, date_column data type is varchar, I have edited that to my post!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I wrote some simple code that extracts month and year from your column:

```
select lpad(extract(month from to_date('2008-09-01' , 'YYYY-MM-DD')),2,'0') 
     ||lpad(extract(year from to_date('2008-09-01' , 'YYYY-MM-DD')),4,'0')  
from dual;
```

if you would like to create date from this, you could do simply like:

```
select to_date(lpad(extract(month from to_date('2008-09-01' , 'YYYY-MM-DD')),2,'0')
               ||lpad(extract(year from to_date('2008-09-01' , 'YYYY-MM-DD')),4,'0')
     ,'MMYYYY')  
from dual;
```

So in your example it would be like that:

```
select to_date(lpad(extract(month from to_date(date_column , 'YYYY-MM-DD')),2,'0')
               ||lpad(extract(year from to_date(date_column  , 'YYYY-MM-DD')),4,'0')
     ,'MMYYYY')  
from test_table;
```

Comment: But you are selecting from dual, not test_table. How would you write that code to select ... from test_table?

Comment: Thank you! Your code seems to be working fine. I just needed to get a SUBSTR from my date format so that it does not include HH:MM:SS

Comment: @jeppoo1 if my response helped you, please accept my answer. Im glad you solved your problem.

Answer (score 1):

If the datatype of the column is *TIMESTAMP*, then try this one!

```
SELECT to_char(date_column, 'YYYYMM') FROM table_name
```

If the datatype is varchar, try out this,

```
SELECT TO_CHAR(CAST(column_name as TIMESTAMP), 'YYYYMM') FROM table_name
```

Comment: this yields the error "ORA-01722: invalid number", the datatype is VARCHAR2.

Comment: Hi, I tried again today (select to_char(cast(column as timestamp), 'YYYY/MM/DD') from table;) and got the error "ORA-01843: not a valid month"

Comment: Tried your second suggestion (the timestamp one), and got error "ORA-01843: not a valid month" but if I set the format to *...as timestamp, 'YYYY/MM/DD'*, it works fine?? What the heck is going on, why does it not allow me the YYYYMM format?

Answer (score 1):

If these are strings and you want a string, how about:

```
select substr(date, 1, 4) || substr(date, 6, 2) as yyyymm
```

You can actually use this on both tables.

If you want to match the dates in the original table to the other, then use:

```
select . . .
from original o join
     testtable tt
     on o.datecol >= to_date(tt.datecol, 'YYYY-MM-DD') and
        o.datecol < to_date(tt.datecol, 'YYYY-MM-DD') + interval '1' month
```